# Does node.js 0.2.5 leak memory?

Tags: memory-leaks, node.js

Node appears to be leaking memory in this simple example.  Can anyone else confirm?

https://gist.github.com/a8eadd54d1058bcda796

Answer (score 1):

I was accidentally sending 2 new requests for each completed request.  One on end and one on close.

Comment: You should flag this as the accepted answer, even if it's your own.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 0.3.1, GC kicks in normally here.

Using `node --trace_gc test.js`, this hardly reaches 5mb:

```
ivo@ivo:~/Desktop$ node --trace_gc test.js
Scavenge 0.9 -> 1.0 MB, 1 ms.
Scavenge 1.9 -> 1.8 MB, 0 ms.
Scavenge 2.6 -> 1.9 MB, 1 ms.
Mark-sweep 2.9 -> 1.8 MB, 6 ms.
Scavenge 2.8 -> 1.8 MB, 0 ms.
Scavenge 2.9 -> 1.9 MB, 0 ms.
```

Another run:

```
ivo@ivo:~/Desktop$ node --trace_gc test.js
Scavenge 0.9 -> 1.0 MB, 1 ms.
Scavenge 1.9 -> 1.8 MB, 0 ms.
Scavenge 2.6 -> 1.9 MB, 1 ms.
Mark-sweep 1.9 -> 1.8 MB, 4 ms.
Mark-sweep 1.8 -> 1.7 MB, 3 ms.
Mark-compact 1.7 -> 1.7 MB, 11 ms.
Scavenge 2.3 -> 1.8 MB, 0 ms.
Scavenge 2.3 -> 1.8 MB, 0 ms.
Scavenge 2.3 -> 1.8 MB, 0 ms.
Scavenge 2.0 -> 1.9 MB, 0 ms.
Mark-sweep 1.9 -> 1.6 MB, 3 ms.
Mark-compact 1.6 -> 1.6 MB, 10 ms.
```

V8 is very intelligent when it comes to GC'ing, one thing you might wanna look out for is that you don't push some references in a global list etc. because that will keep whatever is inside that reference alive.

If you really deal with big amounts of data, consider using `Buffer` and re-allocating on the fly, especially in 0.3.x buffers are extremely fast.